# Online - Open document with client application in web parts

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, document-library

I've created a simple Document Library where I've set in the Advanced Option to open documents in the client application.

I've added a Web Part of this document library on a page (classic experience), but when I try to open a document it opens Office Online.

In the document library the document opens correctly using Word 2016 installed on my PC.

Is there some option I'm missing? Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You need to active **Open Documents in Client Applications by Default** feature from Site Actions > Site Settings > Site collection features.

[image]

Comment: I've already activated this feature but my document is still opening with Office Online from web part.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. What browser do you use? Switch to other browser and check if the file open in the client application.
2. Try to add the site into the trusted site if you use IE.
3. Clear the browser cache and check again.